# Use several ehcache XML files in same project

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd, ehcache

I have a project done with `Spring` framework that uses `ehcache`. This project has a resource file named `xxxx_ehcache.xml` . Now this project has a dependency with a library that is in turn using `ehcache` also, and this library provides a file called `yyyy_ehcache.xml` with some content that can be embedded in the main `xxxx_ehcache.xml`.

I want to embed `yyyy_ehcache.xml` in `xxxx_ehcache.xml`. In `Spring` we have this tag:

```
<import resource="classpath:/someFile.xml" />
```

But I dont know how to do this using ehcache `XSD` grammar.

Comment: I also encountered similar problem. Did you found the solution? thanks.